# Resolving NETBIOS names from Linux

Tags: windows, samba, nsswitch, netbios, host-name-resolution

There's a Windows machine called SUSAN on my network. From a Windows VM on my Linux box I can simply:

```
C:\>ping susan
```

I've followed [this guide](https://www.zulius.com/how-to/resolve-windows-netbios-names-from-linux/) (and looked at several other similar ones) for resolving NETBIOS names from my Linux box itself.

I installed `samba` and `samba-winbind`. I edited this `hosts` line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` from:

```
hosts:      files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
```

to

```
hosts:      files wins mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
```

Apparently I should now be able to ping SUSAN by her name (I can already ping her by her IP). But I'm getting:

```
user@localhost:~ $ ping susan
ping: unknown host susan
```

Answer (score 7):

The answer by The Oilers Fan is mostly valid for Ubuntu-based distros as well. Only the library location is different.

Basically doing

```
sudo apt-get install libnss-winbind
```

has helped in my case.

Answer (score 2):

For a non-Ubuntu based Linux distro, check /lib or /lib64 to make sure libnss_wins.so is installed. If not, then search the Web for the RPM for your Linux distro and install the library. After, run ldconfig from the command line (just type ldconfig and press ENTER as root or su). Took me hours to find this little gap in all the tutorials on the Web. See http://users.atw.hu/linuxandwindows/linuxwinworld-chp-6-sect-1.html for more details.

Comment: I have my libnss_wins.so files in `/usr/lib/`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the NSCD (Name Service Cache Daemon) was causing problems with name resolution on my system. [If I restarted the service](https://serverfault.com/a/76854/50236), I would be able to resolve my host names with NetBIOS for a short time before they would return to resolution failure. I disabled it (with systemd: `systemctl disable nscd.service`) and my name resolution started working.

I had already [installed `winbind`](https://askubuntu.com/a/508020/39012) (`zypper in samba-winbind` on my system), configured my [`/etc/nsswitch.conf` correctly](https://serverfault.com/a/272967/50236) (`hosts: files dns wins`) and [confirmed my changes](https://serverfault.com/q/76853/50236).

Comment: But, [not with Samba 4.4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/279955/13308), sadly.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm running an embedded linux system with about 10MB of free NAND storage space.  I think the above answers are a bit misleading, suggesting that only `libnss_winbind.so` is necessary for other applications (non-Samba apps) to be able to resolve NetBIOS names.

Turns out its just a lightweight wrapper so that other programs can resolve NetBIOS with `winbindd_request_response()`.  Internally, it makes calls to the `winbindd` daemon via socket calls.

And `winbindd` is about 22MB complied, so its much to big for my constraints.

Hopefully this will help other folks looking for a lightweight solution to resolving NetBIOS names.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the winbind Daemon does not run by default (The OS is Centos 8). I have to start it manually.

```
sudo systemctl start winbind
```

And this solved the problem. <3