# Resolve NetBIOS Names via Samba >= 4.4

Tags: networking, samba, samba4, netbios

Through StackExchange, we know how to [configure Linux to resolve NetBIOS names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183317/13308) with older versions of Samba, and I have configured my system in those ways. (I have [installed `winbind`](https://askubuntu.com/a/508020/39012), configured my [`/etc/nsswitch.conf` correctly](https://serverfault.com/a/272967/50236) and [confirmed my changes](https://serverfault.com/q/76853/50236), including [disabling the NSCD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/273721/13308) on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed.)

But now, with Samba 4.4 and later, the Samba developers have opted to [require `winbind` to be running for WINS resolution](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_4.4_Features_added/changed#WINS_nsswitch_module) since they have changed the execution path for WINS queries.

If I include either of `wins` and `winbind` in my `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file, my name resolution fails without the `winbind` dæmon running, like the [Samba page](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_4.4_Features_added/changed#WINS_nsswitch_module) implies will happen. But, even running the `winbind` service, my name queries that would succeed previously (with earlier versions of Samba) are failing, though `nmblookup` returns successfully.

How do I need to configure my client system such that host queries can resolve NetBIOS names with Samba 4.4 and greater? In end-result terms, running Samba 4.4 or later in Linux, how can I ping a Windows machine by its name without DNS?

To clarify: I have a setup working in Samba 4.2. If I upgrade to Samba 4.4, 4.5, or 4.6, maintaining the same settings, name resolution stops working. If I then downgrade back to Samba 4.2, name resolution works again. Other than ensuring the running of the `winbind` dæmon, what else do I need to do differently with these new versions of Samba?

Comment: [Bug report on the Samba-Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12933)